# Laravel 4 Form Model not binding id correctly

Tags: php, laravel-4, model-binding

I am binding a user model to a form and attaching the id.  When i hit submit it places a character code (%7Bid%7D) into the form in place of the id.  The model elements bind to the form properly otherwise.  If I use firebug to change that code to 1 then it fires fine so I know it is an issue with how the id is binding or set.

What am I doing wrong?

I have the following code pieces:

View

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route' => 'users.update', $user->id)) }}
```

Route that is being set in the form

```
Route::post('users/{id}/update', array(
  'uses' => 'UserController@update',
  'as' => 'users.update'
 ));
```

Controller Method that calls the form (UserController)

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //
    $user = $this->user->find($id);
    return View::make('users.edit')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code for the form I'm guessing from the fact you said you are getting `%7Bid%7D` that you've missed a set of curly braces.

Comment: Thanks RMcLeod.  After looking at the curly braces it made me think to go study exactly what other folks have done.  My form creator above should have been: `{{ Form::model($user, array('route' => array('users.update', $user->id))) }}`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It was down to a named route that required a parameter.

```
Route::post('something/new/{id}', array(
    'as' => 'something-new-post',
    'uses' => 'SomeController@newFunction'
));
```

I was calling it using

```
{{ URL::route("something-new-post") }}
```

with the intention of adding the variable later. What I should have been doing is adding an extra parameter..

```
{{ URL::route("something-new-post", $data) }}
```

live and learn..